# On Linux, how should a server sense the uid/gid of its clients, in order to create objects and enforce permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, shared-memory

I'm building a key-value storage system (a distributed service accessed over the network), and would like to support Linux users who may share the service and yet be mutually distrusting (much as with the Linux file system).  To do this my server will need a trustworthy way to determine the uid and gid of its clients.  Does anyone know how this is done?

Related but not identical:   I also will have cases where my server is running on the same machine as a client.  Here, my service uses Linux shm (shmget, shmat) for zero-copy sharing, and shmget apparently inherits the "effective user-id and group-id" as the uid and gid of the shared memory segment.  Are there ways that a service running as root can manipulate its effective user-id and group-id?

Comment: Client UID / GID is not unique and does not reliably convey identity across administrative domains.  Unless you have control over the UIDs created on all the client systems, it's simply impossible to make any reasonable assertion about identity based on UID/GID.  Anyway, they aren't exposed over networks.  You almost certainly don't want to use UID/GID for this - you should use an externally verifiable ID (ideally an existing identity like OIDC, Oauth, or some corporate thing)

Comment: Thanks, Erik.  So basically on Linux, without using an identity management service, I'm limited to hacks like using sysctl and scanning for the KERN_PROC_UID, or playing with "deescalated" privileges in my daemon.  I'm fine with the latter but the former seems really insecure...

Comment: Question: In the "on same machine" case, we have an untrusted user but often inside a container managed by a docker framework and perhaps are on a node managed by Kubernetes.  In this case presumably docker is more or less a trusted service running with escalated permissions.  Does docker expose information about the uid/gid (and administrative domain) of the process inside the container?

Comment: I'm going to close this.  @erik258 is right -- it seems to be a morass and to make things worse, if an application runs in a container, it seems to have PID 1000 because this is one of the ways docker imposes isolation.  Eric's answer is the right one: it has to be done using some sort of verifiable credentialling service.

Answer (score 0):

Closing my own question because:

1. There is no internal standard on Linux.  It can be done in some cases (for example, look up the process id by examining TCP endpoints in /proc/dev/tcp, then look up the process in /proc/pid/stat and read out the uid and gid).  But other cases won't work (docker containers).
2. Across machines you run into the issue of administrative domains and credentials, and there are multiple standards.
3. On a cloud, they basically do (2).  So if my server runs on AWS I might have to integrate the AWS authentication into it, if on Azure or Google, their respective option... But this is apparently the answer!